# Como obtener el valor id desde un table generado dínamicamente en js

Tags: javascript, jquery, axios

Hola estoy intentando obtener el valor ID de mi table generada dinámicamente, y enviarlo a otro archivo js para eliminar o actualizar dicho dato, la idea es que al seleccionar el botón eliminar llame a la función donde se obtiene el ID y el id del botón, y ya en este proceso eliminar o actualizar por medio de axios a un api.

Este es mi HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Listar Platillos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Georama:wght@100;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Contenido principal -->
    
    <div class="flex-container">
      <form>

        <h1 id="titulo">Lista Platillos</h1>
        <a href="agregar.html" class="btn btn-success">Agregar</a>
        <hr>

        <div>
          <table id="tbl-platos" class="tabla-informacion">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Código</th>
                    <th>Nombre</th>
                    <th>Ingrediente</th>
                    <th>Costo</th>
                    <th>Editar</th>
                    <th>Borrar</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>

        <button id="enviar" type="button" value="Aceptar">Aceptar</button>
        <button id="volver" type="button" value="Volver">Volver</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
    <script src="js/platos-servicio.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lista-platos-controlador.js"></script>
    <script src="js/eliminar-plato.js"></script>
    <script src="js/general-service.js"></script>
   
    
  </body>
</html>
```

aquí es donde se genera la tabla dinámica y se manda a imprimir en el HTML lista-platos-controlador.js

```
'use strict';
const tbody = document.querySelector('#tbl-platos tbody');
let mostrar_datos = async() => {
    let platos = await listar_platos();
    tbody.innerHTML = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < platos.length; i++) {
        let fila = tbody.insertRow();
        fila.insertCell().innerHTML = platos[i]['_id'];
        fila.insertCell().innerHTML = platos[i]['codigo'];
        fila.insertCell().innerHTML = platos[i]['nombre'];
        fila.insertCell().innerHTML = platos[i]['ingrediente'];
        fila.insertCell().innerHTML = platos[i]['precio'];
        fila.insertCell().innerHTML = '<button id="btnEditar">Editar</button>';
        fila.insertCell().innerHTML = '<button type="button" id="btnBorrar">Borrar</button>';
    }
};
mostrar_datos();
```

este sería el archivo eliminar-platillo.js donde se supone que voy a obtener los datos y poder envíarlo a axios, realizar mis validaciones necesarias.

```
'user strict';

    // const BotonRegistrar = document.querySelector('#btnBorrar'); Aquí me funciona cuando el botón es creado directamente en html, por ejemplo en agregar me funciona bien y obtengo el id y puedo envíar a guardar normal, pero en table no funciona.
    
        
        const inputId = document.querySelector('#_id');
        
        const BotonBorrar = $(this).closest('table').attr('#btnBorrar');
        
        console.log('Boton borrar: ' + BotonBorrar);
        
        const validar = () => {
        
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Desea eliminar este plato?',
                showDenyButton: true,
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonText: 'Borrar',
                denyButtonText: `No Borrar`,
              }).then((result) => {
                /* Read more about isConfirmed, isDenied below */
                if (result.isConfirmed) {
                  let platillo = {
                    _id: inputId.value
                };
        
                eliminarDatos(platillo, '/eliminar-plato');
                  Swal.fire('Borrado!', '', 'success')
        
                } else if (result.isDenied) {
                  Swal.fire('No borrado', '', 'info')
                }
              })
        
            // let error = false;
        
            // if(inputCodigo.value == '') {
            //     inputCodigo.classList.add('input-error');
            //     error = true;
            // } else {
            //     inputCodigo.classList.remove('input-error');
            // }
        
        };
        
        BotonBorrar.addEventListener('click', validar);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yo lo hice asi:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Listar Platillos</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
      </head>
    
      <body>
    
        <!-- Contenido principal -->
        
        <div class="flex-container">
          <form>
    
            <h1 id="titulo">Lista Platillos</h1>
            <a href="agregar.html" class="btn btn-success">Agregar</a>
            <hr>
    
            <div>
              <table id="tbl-platos" class="tabla-informacion">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Código</th>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Ingrediente</th>
                        <th>Costo</th>
                        <th>Editar</th>
                        <th>Borrar</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
    
            <button id="enviar" type="button" value="Aceptar">Aceptar</button>
            <button id="volver" type="button" value="Volver">Volver</button>
          </form>
        </div>
        
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ=="
        crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
        <script src="lista-platos-controlador.js"></script>
        <script src="eliminar-plato.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

JS  eliminar-plato.js:

```
function fnEditar(rel){
   alert("editando:"+rel);
}
        
function fnEliminar(rel){
   alert("eliminando:"+rel);
}
```

JS lista-platos-controlador.js:

```
const tbody = document.querySelector('#tbl-platos tbody');
        let mostrar_datos = async () => {
            let platos = [
                {
                    "_id": 1,
                    "codigo": "Codigo 1",
                    "nombre": "Nombre 1",
                    "ingrediente": "Ingrediente 1",
                    "precio": 1
                },
                {
                    "_id": 2,
                    "codigo": "Codigo 2",
                    "nombre": "Nombre 2",
                    "ingrediente": "Ingrediente 2",
                    "precio": 2
                }
            ];
            tbody.innerHTML = '';
            for (let i = 0; i < platos.length; i++) {
                let fila = tbody.insertRow();
                fila.insertCell().innerHTML = platos[i]['_id'];
                fila.insertCell().innerHTML = platos[i]['codigo'];
                fila.insertCell().innerHTML = platos[i]['nombre'];
                fila.insertCell().innerHTML = platos[i]['ingrediente'];
                fila.insertCell().innerHTML = platos[i]['precio'];
                fila.insertCell().innerHTML = "<a rel='" + platos[i]['_id'] + "' class='btn btn-info text-white' id='btnEditar' onclick='fnEditar(rel)'>Editar</a>";
                fila.insertCell().innerHTML = "<a rel='" + platos[i]['_id'] + "' class='btn btn-danger text-white' onclick='fnEliminar(rel)' id='btnBorrar'>Borrar</a>";
            }
        };
        mostrar_datos();
```

me vi forzado a probar con datos en duro antes de pasarte la funcionalidad, espero te sirva, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta

Comment: de nada, estamos para ayudar.